# how to open fiddler saz files on mac or online?

Tags: macos, web-browsing

a friend sent me a fiddler record for me to watch.

I have mac and the file he has sent is `X.saz`

I could install fiddler on mac. How can i open these files to watch?

Answer (score 3):

TextWrangler is a free piece of text editing software that is capable of opening these files. 
http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/

You can also unpack them by changing the extension to .zip and unzipping normally. 
http://fiddler.wikidot.com/saz-files